# (Qt) Curl uploading to smtp sends an empty email

Tags: c++, qt, email, curl

I'm using Qt and I recently made a similar application using gmail. Now, I want to send the email from outlook to gmail. **EDIT:** I just tried sending from outlook to outlook using an app password but still empty email in my outlook inbox... **END EDIT** Here is my code:

```
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){  //Writes in the msg.txt
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << "From: \"Me\" <xxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com>" << endl;
    stream << "To: \"Me\" <xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>" << endl;
    stream << "Subject: Subject" << endl;
    stream << msg << endl;  //msg is just a QString variable

}
QString cmd = "ccurl smtp://smtp-mail.outlook.com:587 -v --mail-from \"xxxxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com\" --mail-rcpt \"xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com\" --ssl -u xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx -T \"msg.txt\" -k --anyauth --insecure & pause";
const std::string s = cmd.toStdString();
const char* ccmd = s.c_str();
system(ccmd);
```

Pause is just used for testing purposes. Also, my .exe is named 'ccurl' and the console that appears doesn't throw any error. I do receive an email but it just says something like (Empty)

```
---
Email checked by avast....
```

Thanks for your help!

*Ps. Don't tell me to use libcurl instead*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an empty line between the end of the headers and the start of the message body. Without it, the rest of the message is interpreted as if it was still part of the headers.

Also, `endl` forces a flush in the stream for no good reason, which kills performance when done on files. Just use `\n`.

Comment: Well, you were right! Thanks so much... I wonder why it worked on gmail previously thought.....

Comment: Maybe you were sending a message that contained an empty line somewhere?

Comment: Maybe..... Thought I just copy pasted the code from gmail to outlook... Anyway it worked and now I know why, won't make that mistake twice.